# Connection to ipsec vpn on asus router

Tags: 22.04, vpn, asus, client, ipsec

I have an asus router that has a vpn server based on ipsec

I have all the data I need except the certificate file. Asus provides downloads of the cert for Windows or android for the certificate but no support for Linux.

Do I need to download the cert file or can I bypass it

Has anyone else got round this

Comment: Linux doesn't have any special certificate format. Just download one of the offered formats and test that.

Comment: I'm also trying to achieve the same thing. Did you get yours to work?